# Issue with connecting to my github account on my Mac

Tags: git, github

All of a sudden, since today, I've been facing an issue in accessing my repo. 
For some reason, something seems to have changed.
I cleared my directory, still, it complains about the absence of any such repo.

This is on a Mac OS machine. 
Any clues on this?

I am not even able to clone any of my code.
I've verified that the code is valid on the web.
Any clues on what the error code be?

I remember a dialog box(system) was presented and I wasn't able to recall the password.

Comment: https://github.com/maverick447/hello-world.git this is one of my repo's that is public.

Comment: “I am not even able to clone any of my code.” What does that mean? What do you say to git and what does it say to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the URL used (locally or for cloning the repo unsuccessfully) is an HTTPS one.

Because if it is, the credential cached might not be the right one.
Or it could be the right password, but, if you have [2FA activated on your account](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/configuring-two-factor-authentication), a password would no longer be the right choice (you would instead need a [PAT, Personal Access Token](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line), as a password)

For that, check `git config credential.helper`

On a Mac, it could [return `osxkeychain`](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain).

The other test would be to clone with an SSH URL.

```
git@github.com:maverick447/hello-world.git
```

Assuming you have s[et-up a public/private SSH key](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh), and registered the public one to your account.

Comment: Thank you VonC for helping me out!  Using ssh to clone worked for me.

Comment: @Maverick447 Great! But I would have loved to know why HTTPS was not working.

Comment: I don't have an idea as to why https: is not working. I tried git config credential.helper
osxkeychain. Any other ideas that you have?